# ERROR 500 after migrating to Google Cloud Bitnami Magento

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

I am trying to move my Magento2 site to Google Cloud Bitnami Magento instance. I have followed [this official tutorial](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/magento/administration/migrate/). Everything I did as they said.

Now I am getting `Error 503 Backend fetch failed` when trying to visit with http://
[image]

And, When trying to visit with https:// getting `HTTP ERROR 500`

Here is what `varnishlog` says

```
    *   << BeReq    >> 157       
    -   Begin          bereq 156 fetch
    -   Timestamp      Start: 1548329340.961720 0.000000 0.000000
    -   BereqMethod    GET
    -   BereqURL       /
    -   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
    -   BereqHeader    Host: 35.240.203.52
    -   BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    -   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
    -   BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    -   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-US,en-GB;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,bn-BD;q=0.7,bn;q=0.6
    -   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 45.251.57.253
    -   BereqHeader    grace: none
    -   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    -   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 157
    -   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
    -   VCL_return     fetch
    -   FetchError     no backend connection
    -   Timestamp      Beresp: 1548329340.961740 0.000020 0.000020
    -   Timestamp      Error: 1548329340.961743 0.000023 0.000003
    -   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
    -   BerespStatus   503
    -   BerespReason   Service Unavailable
    -   BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
    -   BerespHeader   Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 11:29:00 GMT
    -   BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
    -   VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
    -   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    -   BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
    -   VCL_return     deliver
    -   Storage        malloc Transient
    -   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
    -   ObjStatus      503
    -   ObjReason      Backend fetch failed
    -   ObjHeader      Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 11:29:00 GMT
    -   ObjHeader      Server: Varnish
    -   ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    -   ObjHeader      Retry-After: 5
    -   Length         280
    -   BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
    -   End            

    *   << Request  >> 156       
    -   Begin          req 155 rxreq
    -   Timestamp      Start: 1548329340.961617 0.000000 0.000000
    -   Timestamp      Req: 1548329340.961617 0.000000 0.000000
    -   ReqStart       45.251.57.253 57967
    -   ReqMethod      GET
    -   ReqURL         /
    -   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
    -   ReqHeader      Host: 35.240.203.52
    -   ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive
    -   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    -   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
    -   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    -   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    -   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-US,en-GB;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,bn-BD;q=0.7,bn;q=0.6
    -   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 45.251.57.253
    -   VCL_call       RECV
    -   ReqHeader      grace: none
    -   ReqURL         /
    -   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    -   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
    -   ReqURL         /
    -   ReqURL         /
    -   ReqURL         /
    -   VCL_return     hash
    -   VCL_call       HASH
    -   VCL_return     lookup
    -   VCL_call       MISS
    -   VCL_return     fetch
    -   Link           bereq 157 fetch
    -   Timestamp      Fetch: 1548329340.961810 0.000193 0.000193
    -   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
    -   RespStatus     503
    -   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
    -   RespHeader     Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 11:29:00 GMT
    -   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
    -   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    -   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
    -   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 156
    -   RespHeader     Age: 0
    -   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
    -   VCL_call       DELIVER
    -   RespUnset      Age: 0
    -   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
    -   RespHeader     Expires: -1
    -   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
    -   RespUnset      Server: Varnish
    -   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 156
    -   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
    -   VCL_return     deliver
    -   Timestamp      Process: 1548329340.961841 0.000224 0.000031
    -   RespHeader     Content-Length: 280
    -   Debug          "RES_MODE 2"
    -   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
    -   Timestamp      Resp: 1548329340.961866 0.000249 0.000025
    -   ReqAcct        414 0 414 269 280 549
    -   End
```

Here database connection file (`/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/etc/env.php`)

[image]

Apache Error Log

```
[Thu Jan 24 12:46:07.179143 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17934:tid 139659954829056] [client 127.0.0.1:54898] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreResolver::__construct() must implement interface Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\FrontendInterface, instance of Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoresData given, called in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111 and defined in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php:66\nStack trace:\n#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreResolver->__construct(Object(Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreRepository), Object(Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoreCookieManager\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http), Object(Magento\\Store\\Model\\StoresData), Object(Magento\\Store\\App\\Request\\StorePathInfoValidator), 'store', NULL)\n#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\\Framework\\Objec...\n'
```

Thank you very much for taking time to read the issue. Now waiting for your response. Please let me know if I can provide anything else.

Comment: please provide webserver errorlog

Comment: @PhilippSander I have added the log.

Comment: have you tried clearing the DI-cache and `bin/magento setup:di:compile`?

Comment: JUST TRIED

Fatal error:  Declaration of
Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Delivery\QuoteCollectio
nPointRepository::save(Temando\Shipping\Api\Data\Delivery\Qu
oteCollectionPointInterface $collectionPoint) must be compat
ible with Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Repository\Qu
oteCollectionPointRepositoryInterface::save(Temando\Shipping
\Api\Data\CollectionPoint\QuoteCollectionPointInterface $col
lectionPoint) in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/tem
ando/module-shipping-m2/Model/ResourceModel/Delivery/QuoteCo
llectionPointRepository.php on line 30

Comment: Now it's no longer showing ERROR 500.New error message is

An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.

Getting back to you with the log

Comment: please don't post this information in the comments. edit your question

Comment: @Philipp Sander, Thanks. I am getting more information.  I am new here, Thanks for your help. I will update the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88743/discussion-between-khaled-bin-amir-and-philipp-sander).